# Git: How do I rename refs/remotes/origin/*

Tags: git

so the deal here is I'm trying to rename a local remote reference. For example, when I run the following command.

```
git show-ref
```

I receive (among others) a couple branches like this

```
refs/remotes/origin/some-name-i-dont-like
```

I'm really not sure how to deal with this, but I would like to rename that branch to something else.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should understand that any item here is a reflection of the item on the remote side, so if you rename anything here, it may be rewritten later.
2. If above mentioned doesn't fear you, let's rename it. Literally rename the reference in the filesystem in `<repo>/.git/refs/remotes/origin/`. You also may take a look at `~/.git/packed-refs`, if exists it's a plain text file of a simple self-explaining syntax.
3. You also should take a look at `<repo>/.git/config`. There's a section `[remote "origin"]` with the key `fetch` like this: `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. Perhaps, you may change the mapping and thus solve you problem
4. You may ask the owner of the remote repository to rename the branch with `git branch -M`. Then you'll get the update with next `git fetch -p` :)

Comment: Yes, ok, all of this work will be done locally. thanks

Comment: So as an aside, if I move .<repo>/.git/refs/remotes/origin/whatever to <repo>/.git/refs/heads/whatever... will that become a local branch?

Comment: I guess I should clarify that the local repo is really the only existing repo... this structure is coming from GIT SVN CLONE

Comment: Well. If the label reside in <repo>/.git/refs/remotes, it's considered remote for some remotes. If in `.git/refs/heads/` - it's considered local. Actually, branches in git are simply "moving labels" so you can do with them whatever you need to do. You may inspect content of `.git/`, internally this part of git is simple and, well, somewhat fun.